# I need to create a href from a value coming from a query to multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Yes, you see I have a var with a title that comes from a query to multiple tables, now I need to open the rest of the content from that row in a separate page. Here is an example:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT columns FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT columns FROM table2 etc(like 6 times)";
    MySQLi etc. etc.
    WHILE( the fetch array thing ){
        $link_id=$row['id'];
        $title=$row['title'];
        echo '<a href="page.php?var='.$tableame.'&var2='.$title.'">'.$link.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

Now, How to determine the table name i.e. `$tablename` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS tablename, columns from table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2' AS tablename, columns..
```

So each result will tell you the table it came from

Comment: Ok, but how do I query the table name in my mysqli_fetch_array?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [mulit-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) combined with some code to fetch the [metadata](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-database-info.htm).

So that at runtime you can parse the meta-data and populate the info dynamically.

Comment: never done that. I mean, that is something I have a great deal of difficulty whit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a column in each table with an abbreviation of the table name inside of it and renaming the abbreviation with a `str_replace()` function call in PHP.